# Graphical glitch on mobile phone when tapping a button

Tags: unity-game-engine, events

I'm running into a strange issue with my 2D game, it seems to revolve around animations. Here is an example of what happens when I tap a button:

[Video of Glitch](https://youtu.be/hIISBzmMZmA)

All it does is move the button to the right. When I do it though the game freezes, but it seems like stuff is still processing because after a fraction of a second it catches up. It only happens once as far as I can tell, after that, it never happens again. It only happens my phone (Moto X4), not on my computer. I'm not doing anything complicated. In fact this is a test program I made only to show this glitch. This is literally all the code I wrote for the application:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Button;
    Vector3 testStart;
    void Start()
    {
        testStart = new Vector3(Button.transform.position.x + 500, Button.transform.position.y);
    }
    public void MoveButton()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Move());
    }
    IEnumerator Move()
    {
        while (Button.transform.position.x != testStart.x)
        {
            Button.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(Button.transform.position, testStart, 600f * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

++++*UPDATE*++++

It might actually have something to do with events in general. I get a similar issue with an event trigger on a sprite animation on my actual game too. When I add this code to make the button move without an event trigger, it works just fine:

```
int intCounter = 0;
private void Update()
{
    if(intCounter == 260)
    {
        MoveButton();
    }
    else
    {
        intCounter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame()` instead of `yield return null` in the `IEnumerator`

Comment: It's quite unsafe using `!=` between floats in a `while` (`Button.transform.position.x` and `testStart.x` could be **nearly equals** but not equals). I suggest `>=` or `<=`

Comment: Hmmm, WaitForEndOfFrame did not make a difference. Thanks though.

Comment: Are you using Button UI Component, EventTrigger or Raycast to invoke `MoveButton()`?

Comment: I'm still a bit new to Unity development, I believe I'm using EventTrigger. It's when you view its properties in the inspector, and you select the method to call for the onclick event.

Comment: If the button is a UI component (located within a Canvas), use the Button Component instead of the EventTrigger Component. With EventTrigger you can choose a lot more listeners (onDrag, onPointerDown, etc.), while Button can only handle onClick (but it's a better handler)

Comment: Hmm, I may have been unclear on the terminology, sorry about that. It is a button component with the OnClick event calling the code.

Comment: Can you please record a better video (record the phone's screen without an external device)

Comment: I updated the video and included the button moved by the update method. You can see it looks smoother where the button that is tapped jumps before the animation is smooth. The low frame rate of the recorder app makes it less pronounced, but in person, it's much more noticeable.

Comment: Maybe it's useless, however, try changing `Time.deltaTime` to `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` or `Time.smoothDeltaTime`